# Conic section General form to Standard form Hyperbola

Tags: conic-sections, completing-the-square

Hi I'm attempting to change $9x^2-18x-y^2-8y-88=0$ to standard form. Here is what I've done:
$$(9x^2 - 18x -1) - (y^2 + 8y +16) = 88+9+16$$
$$(3x-3)^2 - (y+4)^2 = 113$$
$$(3x-3)^2/113 - (y+4)^2/113 = 1$$
 which would be for a horizontal hyperbola.

If I did the above correctly, I'm not sure how I would graph it with the $3x-3$. I also tried factoring the $9$ out first but I end up with another odd problem. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try factoring out the $3$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the odd problem?

Comment: If I factor the 9 at the start I end with 9(x-1)^2/113 - (y+4)^2/113 = 1. I don't believe this matches standard form either.  Most of the standard form examples in the text book show the first fraction being able to be reduced to a multiplier of 1 on the outside of the (). I've missed something somewhere and I cannot see where I've went wrong.

Comment: This is in fact standard form: $\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$. I don't think you went wrong anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely divide out the nine as follows.
$$\frac{(3x-3)^2}{113} - \frac{(y+4)^2}{113} = \frac{(x-1)^2}{113/9} - \frac{(y+4)^2}{113} = 1$$